# centering elements in div

Tags: html, css

I have to center all elements in `div.to_left_60`. I need solution that will work for all elements inside there.
I have set `text-align: center` for this purpose. It works for text, but not for my ul element. I have tried to play with margins and `absolute/relative`, but no luck.

ul.problem is the element I have to center in this div. From jsfiddle you see that white background is not centered.

HTML

```
<div class="to_left_40">gtestsetes</div>
<div class="to_left_60">
    <p>gtestsetes</p>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvZsT7cLwPFCC0joFhZoi6OylhGaIVHBPYn--PrH3nzZdMwH0grA" width="265px" />
    <ul class="problem">
        <li>fsfsd</li>
        <li>fsfsd</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>fsfsd</li>
        <li>fsfsd</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: yellow;
}
ul.problem li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    width: 245px;
    height: 164px;
    padding: 14px 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.to_left_40 {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
}
.to_left_60 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qVTQ4/

**EDIT: (SOLLUTION)**

This helps:

```
ul.problem li{margin:0 auto;}
```

I have modified this sollution:

```
.to_left_60 * {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this way

```
ul.problem li{margin:0 auto;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/qVTQ4/3/)**

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way to rewrite it in the way something like: .to_left_60 > * {    margin:0 auto;} I do not know how to write this correctly: (all elements to have "margin: 0 auto" that are in .to_left_60)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/2y7R8/

All I did was set a width on the ul and add `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Box-align

```
div
{
width:350px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
```

/* Internet Explorer 10 */

```
 display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:center;
-ms-flex-align:center;
```

/* Firefox */

```
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;
```

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */

```
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
```

/* W3C */

```
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
ul
{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

i.e

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul.problem li {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

This can set ui block in center. It make equal margin from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `ul { padding:0; }` Looks like your li's are centered but parent ul has default padding.